# Does Delphi treat .exe files differently based on filename length?

Tags: windows, delphi, exe, delphi-10.4-sydney, short-filenames

I am currently developing an internal tool using Delphi.

If I call the project and therefore the .exe

```
RecUtil
```

It runs fine with no intervention.  However if I name the project

```
RecUpdate
```

It requires user intervention to allow it to run.

This is a command line utility, the only thing that changes between compiles is the filename of the project and by extension of the `.exe`.

Essentially once I go over the 8.3 limit I get different behaviour on the same `.exe`.

Does Delphi compile an `.exe` differently based on the length of the filename?

I am using Delphi 10.4

If I rename the file after compilation everything is fine it works like normal.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "requires user intervention"? Does a dialogue pop up? Does a setting need to be changed? Also, where are you doing the renaming - in some application setting in Delphi? Does the same happen if you rename the file in Windows Explorer after compiling?

Comment: A Dialog pops up asking if I want to run the application.

Comment: Ok, and what does the dialogue say?

Comment: Some security or compatibility application on your computer probably has a whitelist or blacklist. The name of the EXE in itself has no significance, of course. And the length of it certainly doesn't matter. (Another possibility is that your program cares. Maybe you have code like `if Length(ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)) > 12 then DoSomething else DoSomethingElse`.)

Comment: UAC includes some not perfect detection for installers partially based on filenames. Often if just changing the name triggers UAC on a new system it is due to this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239808/windows-installer-detection-whats-the-full-list-of-keywords

Comment: Answer to the question: No!

Comment: To avoid UAC/InstallerDetection, simply give the app a manifest with a `requestedExecutionLevel` specified. This can be handled in the [Application Manifest](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_Options#Manifest_File_.28Windows_Only.29) section of the project options.

Comment: Thanks @Brian I think that might be it.  Also Remy I will set the application Manifest.

Comment: Just to explain @Brians comment. Windows triggers the UAC for filenames containing certain fragments.  The simplest thing is to rename it to not have words such as install, setup, utility, device, driver (just to be sure).

Comment: @RohitGupta Not just file names, but also version info resources, and other string resources, too. However, Microsoft doesn't publish a complete list of keywords it looks for, so the *simplest* (and *correct* and *recommended*) solution is to specify a UAC manifest instead, then the installer detection is disabled, so filename/keywords won't matter at all and can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is entirely to do with the words in the `.exe` name and not the number of characters.

I was naming my `.exe` `recipeUpdate.exe` which seems to trigger this UAC issue.

I removed the word update and it works fine.

Comment: The issue is triggered only if you don't supply a UAC manifest, which (among other things) disables this keyword detection.